# Closest point on 5km line

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance, proximity, turf

Given a point and a line, I am trying to determine the point on the line that is closest to the given point. The given point is always at least fairly close to the line (3-4 meters max)

Originally I was using the `nearestPointOnLine` function from the turf JS library. However, that gives inaccurate results, especially for long lines: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/1440

Another approach I tried was using `ST_ClosestPoint` via postgresql:

```sql
WITH geoms AS (
  SELECT
    ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint (- 86.26725, 34.32582) , ST_MakePoint (- 86.14040, 34.39281)) AS line
    , ST_MakePoint (- 86.19219 , 34.36546) AS point
)
select
    st_distance(point::geography, line::geography) AS i
    , st_distance(st_closestpoint(line, point)::geography, line::geography) AS closest_point_distance
    , st_dwithin(st_closestpoint(line, point)::geography, line::geography, 0.1) AS closest_point_is_close_to_line
from
    geoms
```

| original_distance | closest_point_distance | closest_point_is_close_to_line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.64173838 | 2.68938954 | false |

This runs into the rounding issue described here: [point returned from ST_LineLocatePoint returns false in ST_Contains](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164683)

At this point I am considering getting a small line segment close to the point from PostGIS, then getting the closest point on that line with turf. But that seems very involved, and **I am wondering if I am missing an easy way (via PostGIS or JavaScript) to get the nearest point (to a close by point) on a long line.**

Comment: 5cm is a lot when considering rounding issue... one would expect it more like 10^-6 or smaller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The >0 distance returned by the query is actually correct.

Let's remember that when using the type `geometry`, distances are computed using a straight line while with the type `geography`, the great circle line is used.

So, your data is in `geometry` and you compute the closest point using a straight line (between the start and end point of the line). The closest point is on the line.

Then, you cast to `geography` the computed point and the line. The point doesn't move, but the line is now a great circle and the point is not on the line anymore.

Try running the query using geometries only. The closest point is indeed on the line.

```sql
WITH geoms AS (
  SELECT
    ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint (- 86.26725, 34.32582) , ST_MakePoint (- 86.14040, 34.39281)) AS line
    , ST_MakePoint (- 86.19219 , 34.36546) AS point
)
select
    st_distance(point, line) AS i
    , st_distance(st_closestpoint(line, point), line) AS closest_point_distance
from
    geoms;
           i            | closest_point_distance
------------------------+------------------------
 4.5032368018051133e-07 |                      0
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you segmentize (or densify) your line then it will work better.

```
SELECT
    ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint (- 86.26725, 34.32582) , ST_MakePoint (- 86.14040, 34.39281)),.01) AS line
    , ST_MakePoint (- 86.19219 , 34.36546) AS point
)
select
    st_distance(point::geography, line::geography) AS i
    , st_distance(st_closestpoint(line, point)::geography, line::geography) AS closest_point_distance
    , st_dwithin(st_closestpoint(line, point)::geography, line::geography, 0.1) AS closest_point_is_close_to_line
from
    geoms;
```

Gives me:

```
     i     | closest_point_distance | closest_point_is_close_to_line 
-----------+------------------------+--------------------------------
 0.0341319 |             0.01351816 | t
```